# Get Order Id from Order Item id in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order, items

How to get order details based on **order item id** using simple way.
I can get the order id from **sales_order_item** table and then can lookup in **sales_order** table to fetch sales order details.
Is there a direct way to fetch order details by using **\Magento\Sales\Model\Order** using **order item id**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to load Order Object using Order Item Id.

But if you Load Order Item Object using Item Id then you can directly get the Order Object using function `getOrder`

you can check this `getOrder` function in `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item` class.